# Messaging friends in facebook using graph API2.0 using Message dialog cordova

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am currently developing an app which includes fetching facebook friends(all) and messaging them individually through facebook. I tried the [openFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB) and successfully got it working but.

1. facebooks new graph API does not provide friends list(its just provides friends using the same app)
2. me\tagggable_friends gives me list of all the friends with a token, which can be used to tag them in any stories.

these I cant use for sending messages to individual facebook friends.[There is a message dialog they are saying for IOS.Android , and a send Dialog for websites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), because I am using cordova I need to use the send dialog, It's not working in mobile device

Anyone implemented this in any app, Please share your thought on this I am kind of stuck ,feels like facebook integration for this app is now useless unless I can implement the messaging feature

Thank You,

Comment: you need to use parse.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin I am sorry , I didn't understand what does a parse mean here ? can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: what I mean is Parse Framework from facebook